# The explicit expression of $\frac{δF}{δP}$

Tags: derivatives, variational-analysis

I'm writing simulation code of ferroelectric domain, and there is a math problem that I can't solve.

The expression of $F$ is
$$
F = \frac{|\vec{k} \cdot \vec{P}(\vec{k})|^2}{k^2}.
$$
$\vec{k}$ is a wave-vector in Fourier space, i.e. $\vec{k}=(k_x,k_y)$, and $\vec{P}(\vec{k}) = (P_x,P_y)$ is the Fourier transform of Polarization in real space.

What's the explicit expression of 
$$
\frac{δF}{δP_x}?
$$

More details are available [here](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-8984/22/34/345902).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I only know variational calculus from Physics, so this won't be rigorous.

For fixed $\vec{k}$ you have
$$
F = \frac{(k_x P_x + k_y P_y)(\bar{k}_x \bar{P}_x + \bar{k}_y \bar{P}_y)}{k_x^2 + k_y^2}
$$
and therefore 
$$
d F = \frac{\bar{k}_x \bar{P}_x + \bar{k}_y \bar{P}_y}{k_x^2 + k_y^2} (k_x \,d P_x + k_y \,dP_y) + 
\frac{k_x P_x + k_y P_y}{k_x^2 + k_y^2} (\bar{k}_x \,d \bar{P}_x + \bar{k}_y \,d \bar{P}_y)
$$

According to this, 
$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta P_x} = \frac{\vec{\bar{k}} \cdot \vec{\bar{P}}}{k^2} k_x$$

Comment: But,  $|\vec{k} \cdot \vec{P}(\vec{k})|^2$, this one is not just the square of(kxPx+kyPy), it's the square of its module, Px and Py is complex. Dose this kind of situation still satisfy the derivative principle in real function?

Comment: @KurtFriedman Yes, this changes things. I've edited my answer accordingly